# Tool for calculating AUC Value

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, roc, auc

Is there any tool that can calculate the AUC value from a ROC curve if I already have true positive, true negative, false positive, false negative values.

Comment: You will need those 4 values at a variety of thresholds.

Comment: You might want to consider just using some descriptive stats in your case, [pos. predictive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity), [recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recall_%28information_retrieval%29), [f1 score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score), or something similar. As @Zach points out there is no ROC curve when you only have a 2x2 table.

Comment: @MaxGordon none of those values are necessary to calculate the AUC (or $c$-statistic). You only need estimates of sensitivty and specificity obtained from thresholding a probabilistic marker across all possible ranges.

Comment: @AdamO Those 4 values are used to calculate sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: @Adamo I'm aware of that, it was just a suggestion for what can be done with a simple 2x2 table. As there is no range in a 2x2 table the c-statistic is unattainable as Zach pointed out in the first comment.

Comment: Those person who reported this question as duplicate. Please go through this question....